# Image comparison in Python returns too much of a difference

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to compute the percentage of similarity between these images and exactly identify the difference between these two images.

[image: inout image 1]

[image: input image 2]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np import scipy.misc
img1 = cv2.imread("images/yelp_popover.png") img2 =
cv2.imread("images/yelp_home.png")

print img1.shape

img1 = scipy.misc.imresize(img1, 0.50) img2 =
scipy.misc.imresize(img2, 0.50)

diff = cv2.subtract(img1, img2)

result = not np.any(diff)

if result is False:
    cv2.imshow("Diff ", diff)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But this is identifying the whole second images as the diff, because of the mask that is applied because of the popover. Is there any way to optimize to identify the dialog box as the difference between the images?

Comment: Your algorithm is too naive to be useful. At very least, try to adjust color and light of the pictures globally to get a best match, and then use a theshold in the comparison. More advanced techniques may involve Fourier (and other) transforms.

Comment: @WhatsUp, Thanks for your response. I have some understanding adjusting the colour. Could you please provide some information what is meant by "Light".

Comment: This still is very complicated. Please have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space to get an idea of color spaces, e.g. RGB, HSV, LAB, ... If I were you, I'd begin with black-and-white pictures, so that one doesn't worry about colors, and/or try to differentiate the picture and detect boundary matches, etc. It's still a complicated project, I'd say.